# Star Team to TFS 2010 Migration with history

Tags: starteam, tfs-migration

I want to migrate from star team 2005 to TFS 2010 with HISTORY. Is there any tool or any way where I can do it cost effectively. I know about Timely Migration tool, but it is too expensive.

Answer (score 2):

There is no tool out there to do this.  You are stuck with paying for Timely Migration or writing it yourself.  Capturing history from StarTeam is extremely complex.  The reason for this is because of what the view looks like historically.  You can roll back the view to a point in time, and this alone works very well, but rolling back to every point in time where a change happened to the view is practically impossible to do using the API.  This is because 1) not everything has an Audit record, so you can't use the audits, and 2) the audit records are purged, 3) there is a special feature to "play back" the history of the view to generate the listener events (requires MPX), but this will miss many events, 4) when items are shared, configured, branched, etc., these do not generate any audits in the project, 5) even if they did, getting every single change requires iterating through the view history down to the second to get all of the changes by analyzing the differences.  So that means if your project has been active for a month and each time you analyze the two view configurations to diff them it takes 5 seconds, then actually migrating your project would take 5 months, and in the meantime it would be locked down.

So the next way to do this would be to establish "baselines" to compare.  Using build labels is a good starting point if you have nightly or continuous builds in your project, or even just certain builds that were QA certified.  This way you can use these baselines as points for diff/compare and then bring in the history that way.  While this isn't as granular as a full history, it is by definition getting the most important differences to migrate over.

However, keep in mind that even doing it this way does not maintain the links between branch/merge points across the different branches/views.  The only way to do this would be to go directly into the StarTeam database to get this information.

I went through all of these steps to try and write my own suite of tools to migrate from StarTeam to Subversion.  It was fun and interesting and imperfect but had some promise, but ultimately never finished it.  Part of the reason was because the time involved would have been far more than the value I got from it.

Which brings you inevitably to the most important question: what is the business value of maintaining full history?  After going through this many times with project teams as a StarTeam administrator, more than 90% of the time it was readily apparent that the better approach is a cut-over.  Make a time where you can begin working on new work in the new system and freeze work in the old system.  It usually can be done with very little down time for the project team.  You can even start by bringing over a history of Production releases to create a rough timeline in the new system.  Use your existing comparison tools, either in TFS or BeyondCompare or elsewhere, to reproduce each state of your project source code, doc, etc. and reconcile it with your TFS project by checking in or deleting files as needed, and labeling your TFS project for each build you bring over.  Line up all your TFS builds, work items, users, roles, etc, and make sure everything is ready.  Then at time of cut-over, take the latest development snapshot from StarTeam over and do one more update to your TFS project.  Lock your Starteam users out of the project (for checkins anyway), and begin working in TFS.  Your TFS project will have a rough history of the most significant baselines and you will be able to keep your StarTeam repository open to users in case more history is needed.

One other thing to consider is how to create a permanent archive of your project.    If your repository is small enough it is doable, but gets more time intensive the larger your project is. First, copy your entire database and vault to a separate instance and get that copy up and running.  Then delete all other projects EXCEPT the projects you want to archive off.  Run an online purge and make sure to run it to completion.  You may need to restart your server and purge several times.  When you are done, your entire repository should contain only the files and database records that are needed by your project.  At this point you can back up your database and vault and keep them indefinitely.  This reduces the size of your existing StarTeam repository.

Haven't used StarTeam in over 3 years but that was a fun ride back in time.  Hope you found it useful.